# Python socket ConnectionRefusedError but only when not on 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tkinter, connection-refused

I was looking everywhere and I couldn't find a solution. The problem is:

When I run server as on ip `127.0.0.1` it's everything alright. I can send  message from client to server and server send broadcast to the all clients. But the problem starts when its not on `127.0.0.1` but on IPv4. Then the error is:

```
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\python\socket\clientTk.py", line 157, in <module>
    client = Client(HOST, PORT)
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\python\socket\clientTk.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.sock.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

The code of `serverTk.py`:

```
import socket
import threading

HOST = input("Type your ip (none for 127.0.0.1): ")
if HOST == "":
    HOST = "127.0.0.1"

PORT = input("Type your port (none for 9939): ")
if PORT == "":
    PORT = 9939
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

#broadcast
def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            print(f"{message}")
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break
    

#receive
def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(address)}!")

        client.send("NICK".encode('utf-8'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024)


        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print(f'Nickname of the client is {nickname}')
        broadcast(f"""[SERVER] {nickname} connected
""".encode('utf-8'))
        client.send("You have been succesfuly connected\n".encode('utf-8'))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client, ))
        thread.start()

print("Starting server...")
receive()
```

And the `clientTk.py` is:

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import simpledialog
from time import sleep

PORT = 9939

class Client:

    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))
        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()
        
        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Choose a nickname", parent=msg)

        self.gui_done = False

        self.running = True

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.title(f"InChat: {self.nickname}")
        #self.win.geometry('450x400')
        self.win.configure(bg="#222222")
        self.win.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.space = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="", bg="#222222")
        self.space.config(width=1)
        self.space.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)
        
        #text "chat"
        #self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="#222222", fg="#00ff00")
        #self.chat_label.config(font=("Consolas", 12))
        #self.chat_label.place(x=10, y=5)

        #history of chat
        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win, bg = '#000000', fg = '#22ee00', width=50, height=20)
        self.text_area.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        #text "Message"
        #self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Message:", bg="#222222", fg="#00ff00")
        #self.msg_label.config(font=("Consolas", 12))
        #self.msg_label.place(x=10, y=50)

        #message place
        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=1, bg = '#000000', fg = '#11cc11', width=38)
        self.input_area.bind('<Return>', self.write)
        self.input_area.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")

        #"send" button
        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text = "Send", width=10, height=1, command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=("Consolas", 12))
        self.send_button.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)
        
        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self, event = "1"):
        try:
            text = self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')
            self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')
            self.input_area.insert('end', text.replace("\n", ""))
            message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
            self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')
        except:
            self.text_area.configure(state='normal')
            self.text_area.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "\n [FATAL ERROR] Lost connection with server")
            self.text_area.configure(state='disabled')
            self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)
        
    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'NICK':
                    self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("[FATAL ERROR] Connection lost")
                self.sock.close()
                break
##############################

now = False
HOST = ""
PORT = 9939

def getHostIp():
    win2 = tkinter.Tk()

    global host
    host = tkinter.StringVar()
    
    lbl = tkinter.Label(win2, text="Type host name (ip)")
    entryIp = tkinter.Entry(win2, width=12, textvariable=host)
    btnConfirm = tkinter.Button(win2, text="Confirm", command=lambda : ipGet(win2))

    
    global port
    port = tkinter.IntVar()
    
    lblP = tkinter.Label(win2, text="Type port:")
    entryPort = tkinter.Entry(win2, width=12, textvariable=port)
    
    lbl.pack()
    entryIp.pack()
    lblP.pack()
    entryPort.pack()
    btnConfirm.pack()
    win2.mainloop()


def ipGet(root):
    HOST = host.get()
    root.destroy()


getHostIp()
#HOST = input("Type host name: ")

if HOST == "":
    HOST = "127.0.0.1"
if PORT == 0:
    PORT = 9939
    
client = Client(HOST, PORT)
```

How to solve it?
Please help.
Thank you.

@Edit:
I made a short version of client, I'm not sure if there are all information that needed.

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import simpledialog
from time import sleep


PORT = 9939

class Client:

    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))
        msg = tkinter.Tk()

        

HOST = input("Type host name: ")

if HOST == "":
    HOST = "127.0.0.1"
if PORT == 0:
    PORT = 9939
    
client = Client(HOST, PORT)
```

Comment: You probably didn't open the firewall to your server or something. It's way more code than I'm willing to sift through; you need a [mcve]

Comment: Do I need to open firewall when its local? Like only on local wifi connection?

Comment: If it's on wifi then you can usually broadcast a server across your network by launching on `0.0.0.0`. But again, I don't want to trawl through all the code; you need to narrow things down on your end first

Comment: @roganjosh It works but only on same computer. When I try to open serven on one computer and client on other (both are connected to same wi-fi) the same error shows up.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is known as _local_ host for a reason

Comment: But I want to send a message from one computer to another in the same wi-fi connection. And `127.0.0.1` works only when I want to test it on 1 computer. It does not send farther than one computer.  Same thing I see on `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: So we go full circle back to "you probably didn't open the port on your firewall"

Comment: Oh ok... So to local wifi connection I have to open firewall... ok... Thanks.